# Invalidate View Flipper Added View

Tags: android, android-view, textview, viewflipper

I have a view flipper used in my application and added some view in it. Which are added perfectly and Now i want to set text of Text View of an added view.

I Inflate the textview and settext of the and invalidate the flipper but the Text not reflect on screen.

```
LayoutInflater inflate = getLayoutInflater();

View view = (View) inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_ask_ques_image,
        null);

TextView txtQuesName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
System.out.println(txtQuesName.getText());
txtQuesName.setText("Type ID " + i + " ");
flipper.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have added the view to the view flipper.

Essentially each time you call LayoutInflater.inflate you're constructing a completely new instance of the view hierarchy, so it won't access the previous one you've got on the screen.

You wish to either do a findViewById on the existing view (not a newly inflated view) to access the correct textview instance, or you want to keep a reference to the textview when you added it to the flipper (assuming it was programmatically added).